# Channel entries tag filter based on custom date field

Tags: channel-entries

I'm using the [JSON](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/json) plugin from Devotee to write a small API for a third-party.

Another developer (honestly) has added a 'start_date' custom field for when a particular offer is valid from. The 'entry_date' field is defaulting to the date the entry is added.

Is there a way of doing something similar to 'show_future_entries' but with a custom field? I only want entries to be returned where the start_date is before today/current_time.

Here's my simple JSON template code:

```
{exp:json:entries 
channel="offers" 
search:product_category="Food - chilled-dairy" 
show_future_entries="no" 
fields="title|offer_start_date|offer_end_date|product_image|product_weight|product_offer_message|
product_offer_image|...snip"}
```

Thanks in advance,
Brett

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've struggled with this problem in the past, and there's not really a native way to fix this. There are two third-party solutions that I'm aware of that will give you an easy fix:

**Low Events: http://gotolow.com/addons/low-events**

Provides a wrapper for the channel-entries tag which allows you to do what you set out to do.

**Solspace Date Field Filter: http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/date_field_filter/**

This allows you to pick another field for date-based filtering. Different approach, for your ends same effect. This is $10 cheaper then Low's awesome module, and might be a better fit.

I'm sure there are ways to build this yourself with a custom plugin / whatever, but I'm more of a front-end kind of guy, plus: if you can fix this by spending 20 bucks and 5 minutes, to me that's always cheaper then spending an hour or two trying to work out how to fix this :). Hope this helps!

- Steven

Comment: Ouch, totally forgot: I doubt you can keep using `json:entries` for this, but you can just use `channel:entries` and format your template as json. Depending on how strict the API is you can use [HTTP Header](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/http-header) to send the proper header :).

Comment: I've used Solspace Date Field Filter and it works great for this purpose.  The only limitation I have run into so far with it is that it doesn't bring all of the default behaviour of the "regular" date field with it - for example, you can't use date headings.  But using it as a limiter with a static or even dynamic start or end date on the loop works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The docs have an example of setting the start_on parameter dynamically. [Check here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#start-on)

Does require a bit of php though.

Comment: Erwin, I had a look at the stop_before but couldn't figure out how to use it with a custom field.

Comment: Ah sorry, hadn't noticed the custom field bit, in that case the answers above are solid options.